# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

---

### i want to fix it and i want like when user1 give user2 a role name zzz and user1 dont have ccc role bot remove role zzz from user2 bec user1 dont have ccc role

```
(node:4544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at pluck (C:\Dev\DiscordTickets-master\auto.js:5:18)
    at hasRole (C:\Dev\DiscordTickets-master\auto.js:9:8)
    at newMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs.then.logs (C:\Dev\DiscordTickets-master\auto.js:21:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:4544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4544) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.


function pluck(array) {
    return array.map(function(item){ return item["name"]})
}

function hasRole(mem, role){
    if(pluck(mem.roles).includes(role)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    var cca = newMember.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === 'bots');
    newMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs().then(logs => {
        if(oldMember.roles.size < newMember.roles.size) {
            var role25 = newMember.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'zzz');
      var ex = logs.entries.first().executor;
      if(!hasRole(ex, "ccc"))return newMember.removeRole( role25 );  
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: `mem.roles` is undefined this your `pluck` method does not receive an array as an input but an `undefined` which does no thave a property map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in this part. `if(!hasRole(ex, "ccc"))return newMember.removeRole( role25 );` [`executor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=executor) its a user, you need get member from user.

Better check role like this.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    var cca = newMember.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === 'bots');
    newMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs().then(logs => {
        if(oldMember.roles.size < newMember.roles.size) {
            let role25 = newMember.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'zzz');
            let ccRole = newMember.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'ccc');
            var ex = newMember.guild.members.get(logs.entries.first().executor.id);
            if(!ex.roles.has(ccRole.id))return newMember.removeRole( role25 );  
        }
    })
});
```